# Form on submit event not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, html, forms, eventhandler, onsubmit

I am new to web dev and for a school exercise, I'm working on something where I want to execute javascript of form submit event.

```html
<head>
  <script>
    function foobar() {
      alert('Form submit event hit!');
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="document.myForm.submit()">
  <form name="login" id="login" action="login.php" method="POST" onsubmit="foobar();">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" .../>
    <input type="hidden" name="password" .../>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

When i execute this, I see that form gets submitted successfully that I see the output after successful login. But, I don't see the submit event's handler Java script getting called or hit. I'm sure I'm missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I start with x.html that redirects to login.php/login form. But when login form "Login" button is clicked, which is 'submit' type I cannot call the handler function, even if I specify via onsubmit='' option of form.

Comment: Add `event` argument for `onsubmit="foobar(e);"` and `function foobar(e) {...}`. Then use it in your function.

Comment: thanks. But didn't help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dthsLey7/11/